# Funny results with pandas argsort

Tags: python, pandas

I think I have hit on a bug in pandas.  I was hoping to get some help either verifying the bug or helping me figure out where my logic error is located in my code.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas, numpy, StringIO

def sq_fixer(sr):
    sr = sr.where(sr != '20200229')
    ranks = sr.argsort().astype(float)
    ranks[ranks == -1] = numpy.nan

    return ','.join(ranks.astype(numpy.str))

def correct_date(sr):

    date_fixer = lambda x: pandas.datetime(x.year -100, x.month, x.day) if x > pandas.datetime.now() else x
    sr = pandas.to_datetime(sr).apply(date_fixer).astype(pandas.datetime)

    return sr 

txt = '''ID,RUN_START_DATE,PUSHUP_START_DATE,SITUP_START_DATE,PULLUP_START_DATE
1,2013-01-24,2013-01-02,,2013-02-03
2,2013-01-30,2013-01-21,2013-01-13,2013-01-06
3,2013-01-29,2013-01-28,2013-01-01,2013-01-29
4,2013-02-16,2013-02-12,2013-01-04,2013-02-11
5,2013-01-06,2013-02-07,2013-02-25,2013-02-12
6,2013-01-26,2013-01-28,2013-02-12,2013-01-10
7,2013-01-26,,2013-01-12,2013-01-30
8,2013-01-03,2013-01-24,2013-01-19,2013-01-02
9,2013-01-22,2013-01-13,2013-02-03,
10,2013-02-06,2013-01-16,2013-02-07,2013-01-11
3347,,2008-02-27,2008-04-10,2008-02-13 
3588,2004-09-12,,2004-11-06,2004-09-06 
3784,2003-02-22,,2003-06-21,2003-02-19 
593,2009-04-03,,2009-06-01,2009-04-01 
4148,2003-03-21,2002-09-20,2003-04-01,2003-01-01 
4299,2004-05-24,2004-07-23,,2004-04-22 
4590,2005-05-05,2005-12-05,2005-04-05,
4830,2001-06-12,2000-10-12,2001-07-28,2001-01-28 
4941,2006-11-08,2006-12-19,2006-07-19,2007-02-24 
1416,2004-04-03,2004-05-19,2004-02-06,
1580,2008-12-20,,2009-03-19,2008-12-19 
1661,2005-10-03,2005-10-26,2005-09-12,2006-02-19 
1759,2001-10-18,,2002-01-17,2001-10-17 
1858,2003-04-14,2003-05-17,,2002-12-17 
1972,2003-06-01,2003-07-14,2002-12-14,
5905,2000-11-18,2001-01-13,,2000-11-04 
2052,2002-06-11,,2002-08-23,2001-12-12 
2165,2006-10-01,,2007-02-27,2006-09-30 
2218,2007-09-19,,2008-02-06,2007-09-09 
2350,2000-08-08,,2000-09-22,2000-01-08 
2432,2001-08-22,,2001-09-25,2000-12-16 
2611,2005-05-07,,2005-06-05,2005-03-26 
2612,2005-05-06,,2005-05-26,2005-04-11 
7378,2009-08-07,2009-01-30,2010-01-20,2009-06-08 
7550,2006-04-08,,2006-06-01,2006-04-01  '''

df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(txt))

sequence_array = ['RUN_START_DATE', 'PUSHUP_START_DATE', 'SITUP_START_DATE', 'PULLUP_START_DATE']
xsequence_array = ['X_RUN_START_DATE', 'X_PUSHUP_START_DATE', 'X_SITUP_START_DATE', 'X_PULLUP_START_DATE']

df[sequence_array] = df[sequence_array].apply(correct_date, axis=1)

fix_day = lambda x: x if x > 0 else 29
fix_month = lambda x: x if x > 0 else 02
fix_year = lambda x: x if x > 0 else 2020

for col in sequence_array:

    xcol = 'X_{0}'.format(col)
    df[xcol] = ['{0:04d}{1:02d}{2:02d}'.format(fix_year(c.year), fix_month(c.month), fix_day(c.day)) for c in df[col]]

df['X_AS_SEQUENCE'] = df[xsequence_array].apply(sq_fixer, axis=1)
```

When I run the code most of the results are correct.  Take for example index 6:

```
In [31]: df.ix[6]
Out[31]: 
ID                                       7
RUN_START_DATE         2013-01-26 00:00:00
PUSHUP_START_DATE                      NaN
SITUP_START_DATE       2013-01-12 00:00:00
PULLUP_START_DATE      2013-01-30 00:00:00
X_RUN_START_DATE                  20130126
X_PUSHUP_START_DATE               20200229
X_SITUP_START_DATE                20130112
X_PULLUP_START_DATE               20130130
X_AS_SEQUENCE              1.0,nan,0.0,2.0
```

However, certain indices seem to throw pandas.argsort() for a loop.  Take for example index 10:

```
In [32]: df.ix[10]
Out[32]: 
ID                                    3347
RUN_START_DATE                         NaN
PUSHUP_START_DATE      2008-02-27 00:00:00
SITUP_START_DATE       2008-04-10 00:00:00
PULLUP_START_DATE      2008-02-13 00:00:00
X_RUN_START_DATE                  20200229
X_PUSHUP_START_DATE               20080227
X_SITUP_START_DATE                20080410
X_PULLUP_START_DATE               20080213
X_AS_SEQUENCE              nan,2.0,0.0,1.0
```

The argsort should return `nan,1.0,2.0,0.0` instead of `nan,2.0,0.0,1.0`.

I have been on this for three days.  At this point I am not sure if it is me or a bug.  I am not sure how to backtrace it to get an answer.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I'm using 0.11.0-dev and then get an error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'year'` in Line 71

Comment: @waitingkuo There was a minor mistake in the code. I have put the correct code on pastebin.  The long and the short of it was that I used pandas.datetime and not numpy.datetime64.  http://pastebin.com/Fwbmsk5F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interpreting the result of `argsort` incorrectly.  `argsort` does not give the ranking of the values.  Use the [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank) method if you want to rank the values.

The values in the Series returned by `argsort` give the corresponding positions of the original values after dropping the NaNs.  In your case, since you convert 20200229 to NaN, you are argsorting `NaN, 20080227, 20080410, 20080213`.  The non-NaN values are

```
nonnan = [20080227, 20080410, 20080213]
```

The result, `NaN, 2, 0, 1` says:

```
argsort     sorted values
  NaN       NaN
   2        nonnan[2] = 20080213
   0        nonnan[0] = 20080227
   1        nonnan[1] = 20080410
```

So it looks OK to me.

Comment: I was confusing argsort with rank.  A quick code fix using a double argsort and my code was ready to go.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If you need to rank the values, use the `rank` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort a Series, just use sort_values() or rank() function:

```
In [2]: a=pd.Series([3,2,1])

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
0    3
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
In [4]: a.sort_values()
Out[4]:
2    1
1    2
0    3
dtype: int64
```

if you use argsort(), this will give you the position of each element in the sorted series, 
in this case, 1 should be in the 0 position and 2 should be in the 1 position and 3 should be in the 2 position

```
In [5]: a.argsort()
Out[5]:
0    2
1    1
2    0
dtype: int64
```